# Route not found in after change to another file

Tags: laravel

Before this I put the route in web.php and its works fine. Then I create another route which is development.php and didn't work.

routes\Backend\development.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\DevelopmentController;    
Route::get('/email/register-partner',  'DevelopmentController@register_partner');
Route::get('/email/admin-notify-partner-register',  
'DevelopmentController@adminNotifyPartnerRegister');
Route::get('/email/send-invitation',  'DevelopmentController@sendInvitation');
Route::get('/email/account-activated',  'DevelopmentController@accountActivated');
Route::get('/email/request-quotation-to-admin',  
'DevelopmentController@requestQuotationToAdmin');
Route::get('/email/request-quotation-to-customer',  
'DevelopmentController@requestQuotationToCustomer');
Route::get('/email/success-payment-to-admin',  'DevelopmentController@successPaymentToAdmin');
Route::get('/email/waiting-for-payment',  'DevelopmentController@waitingForPayment');
```

[image]

```
Laravel version : 7
```

Comment: mention laravel version in question

Comment: I use laravel 7

Comment: you cannot include routes like this `use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\DevelopmentController;`  you need to configure your 
`RouteServiceProvider` as @john-lobo mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You have register your custom route file in

```
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider
```

In boot method

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/Backend/development.php'));
    });
}
```

if still not working after adding above code then run

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check file register in ServiceProvider and run the command line:

```
php artisan route:clear
```